# Google Chrome Developer Tools not showing css filename next to css

Tags: css, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, prefixfree

It's a bug of google chrome or there are some guidelines which i should stick to, to return that feature?
[image]
[image]

Thank you.

*UPDATED*
Issue was caused by prefixfree.

Comment: On some css files it shows it and on some it doesn't. Don't understand why...

Comment: maybe externals css? (cdn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple cases,
1. You are using less CSS files.
2. The CSS class is on same page.
3. Class is generated by a plugin

Comment: any source/ref for that?

Comment: You mean LESS css files? Not using LESS or SASS.
What do you mean by "on the same page"?
Not using any plugins either.
Everything was working on earlier versions of Google Chrome and then suddenly disappeared.

Comment: On the same page means added class in style tag on the same HTML page and not in any external CSS file

Comment: Nope, there is no filename to all styles on the page. But i will try to remove inline styles, moving all to external files.

Comment: Found the problem. It was prefixfree. Have to report that issues to them.

Comment: Here’s the -prefix-free thread for anyone interested: https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/issues/208#issuecomment-64770695

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the save problem, but my case it happened because of a old local folder map in the Sources tab.